# One form action inside several tabs

Tags: html, forms

I am having a hard time with form actions. I would like to know if it is possible to have one form action over several tabs. In the last tab the user clicks the submit button. Could this be done?

**Html/Form action**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id ="tabs-1">
        <div id=panel>
            <br>
            <form action="xx.php" method="post" name="post">
             Form Content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id ="tabs-2">
        <div id=panel>
            <br>
            Form Content

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id ="tabs-3">
        <div id=panel>
            <br>
            Form Content

                 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post "/>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: why are you extending the <form> between <divs>? the way you have your HTML, it's not allowed. Do you need the <form> to be accessible by all tabs? Or do you need each tab to have a different action?

Comment: I didnt know about that. I can see why is now giving me issues. But I want one form to be accessible by all tabs.

Comment: just move the form outside of the id="tabs" div. when rendered, all the tabs should be inside the form, and ANY submit button should trigger the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the form open/close tags outside of the divs, and change the divs to fieldsets:

```
<form action="xx.php" method="post" name="post">

    <fieldset id ="tabs-1">
    ...
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id ="tabs-2">
    ...
    </fieldset>
    ...etc

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since tags cannot span across unclosed tags, you need to move the <form> outside of the div id="tabs". Something like:

```
<form action="xx.php" method="post" name="post">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id ="tabs-1">

        </div>

        <div id ="tabs-2">

        </div>

        <div id ="tabs-3">

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

That way, ANY submit or reset button in your tabs will target the form.